# Convert Python Numpy array to array of single arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a feeling that this is very easy but I can't quite figure out how to do it.  Say I have a Numpy array

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

How do I convert this to

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

In an easy way?

Thanks

Comment: To be precise: you're trying to convert `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])` to `np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])`? Or convert it to a traditional Python list of lists?

Comment: oh sorry. Numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.newaxis`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4] 
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a[:,np.newaxis]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> np.reshape(a, (-1, 1))
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

If you want normal python list then use `list comprehension`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4]) 
>>> [[x] for x in a]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way that comes to mind is:

```
>>> new = []
>>> for m in a:
        new.append([m])
```

but this creates normal Python's list of lists, I'm not sure if this is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,4]

>>> B = [[x] for x in A]

>>> print B
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```